# Using single microcontroller I/O to enable/disable two transceivers

Tags: microcontroller

I am using ATMega16L microcontroller, and two IR transceivers for communication with devices. The transceiver I am using is TFBS4650-TR1 which can be enabled using the 'SD' pin. Can I enable both transceivers at the same time just by connecting one I/O pin as shown in the schematic below? Is it safe to do so or is there any other way to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one GPIO output can be used to drive two logic inputs, such as the SD pins.

Yes, the direct connection shown in the schematic is fine to use, as the microcontroller and the transceivers operate on the same voltage levels.

The grounds of the three devices must be common.

Assuming the devices are near each other on the same board, the schematic shown will be safe and sufficient. If, however, the transceivers are a significant distance from the microcontroller, then issues such as ringing on the GPIO-to-SD lines, and noise picked up along those traces, will need to be addressed. Typically, a simple RC damping / decoupling arrangement would suffice in such cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Anindo. Can this also be applied to two h-bridges connected to two separate DC motors and using PWM1 for Input_1 and a GPIO as Input_2 of the h-bridge?

Comment: @DavidNorman That would depend on the operating logic voltages of the H-bridges, the lengths of traces, and so on. Without looking at a schematic and specific part numbers, this is difficult to confirm.

Comment: Alright, I will soon update my question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that should work fine.

Here are some things to check for, the next time a question like this comes up:

1. Make sure that the input pins are high-impedance.  They almost always are.  Two exceptions are: an optocoupler where you are driving an internal led, or a bjt transistor input.  In either of these cases, the datasheet will mention the required drive current.  Parts with high-impedance inputs don't draw any significant current.
2. Make sure the pins are *only* inputs. I'm working with an IC that has a Reset input, which is also an open-drain style output. You don't want one of the sensors to drive the other one :)
3. If you are wanting to switch the line on and off rapidly, then you'll need to consider the input capacitance.  But, not for this example.

Good luck :)